# Best graphics hardware for large point clouds in rviz

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am putting together some desktop computers that will be running ubuntu 12.04. I know from experience that rviz gets very slow when displaying a very large point cloud (or a large number of cubes etc). What should I be looking for in terms of hardware to mitigate this problem?

Is system memory, GPU memory or something else the bottleneck? How about specialized graphics cards such as the nvidia quadro cards (designed for CAD)?

Thanks in advance,
Hugh

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/47514/best-graphics-hardware-for-large-point-clouds-in-rviz/) by [revoc25](https://answers.ros.org/users/3528/revoc25/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-11-05

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2012-11-08**:
How large is very large (both in terms of number of points and rough shape/area/volume)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some people know more about this than I do. For good performance you need something that does 3D well on X11 and Linux.

Various nVidia cards are often reported to work well. I am sure some others do, too, but have no experience to confirm it.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have a Lenovo W510 (Quad-core, 8GB RAM, SSD, nVidia Quadro FX 880M) and I can display clouds of 1/2 million to 1 million points without a problem. However, it does take a lot of power and going over 1 million might no be so smooth anymore. I noticed that it eventually becomes harder to move around the virtual scene with the load is too high.

---

Originally posted by [Benoit Larochelle](https://answers.ros.org/users/216/benoit-larochelle/) with karma: 867 on 2012-11-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1